# SharePoint 2013 Share functionality don't display Update information In IE

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When I try to share file with user X his information looks up to date to me ( i am not member or new member of the site).

But when old one try, he is not able to see updated information of user.

Is there a recommended or used list of users for every user? Why some users see old information? Are they cached somewhere?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with internet explorer as in chrome it displays correctly. Reseting didnt help it.

Answer (score 0):

On site you have problem:
F12
Choose console
type to see stored data :localStorage 
type to clear data: localStorage.clear();